# Issues with JSON_EXTRACT in Presto for keys containing ' ' character

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using Presto(0.163) to query data and am trying to extract fields from a json.

I have a json like the one given below, which is present in the column 'style_attributes':

```
"attributes": {
    "Brand Fit Name": "Regular Fit",
    "Fabric": "Cotton",
    "Fit": "Regular",
    "Neck or Collar": "Round Neck",
    "Occasion": "Casual",
    "Pattern": "Striped",
    "Sleeve Length": "Short Sleeves",
    "Tshirt Type": "T-shirt"
}
```

I'm unable to extract field 'Short Sleeves'.
Below is the query i'm using:

Select JSON_EXTRACT(style_attributes,'$.attributes.Sleeve Length') as length from table;

The query fails with the following error- Invalid JSON path: '$.attributes.Sleeve Length'

For fields without ' '(space), query is running fine.

I tried to find the resolution in the Presto documentation, but with no success.

Comment: To Google Searchers ' ' in the title means the space character.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
presto:default> select json_extract_scalar('{"attributes":{"Sleeve Length": "Short Sleeves"}}','$.attributes["Sleeve Length"]');
     _col0
---------------
 Short Sleeves
```

or

```
presto:default> select json_extract_scalar('{"attributes":{"Sleeve Length": "Short Sleeves"}}','$["attributes"]["Sleeve Length"]');
     _col0
---------------
 Short Sleeves
```

> **JSON Function Changes**
>
> The :func:`json_extract` and :func:`json_extract_scalar` functions now
>   support the square bracket syntax:
>
> ```
> SELECT json_extract(json, '$.store[book]'); 
> SELECT json_extract(json,'$.store["book name"]');
> ```
>
> As part of this change, the set of characters
>   allowed in a non-bracketed path segment has been restricted to
>   alphanumeric, underscores and colons. Additionally, colons cannot be
>   used in a un-quoted bracketed path segment. Use the new bracket syntax
>   with quotes to match elements that contain special characters.
>
> https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/c73359fe2173e01140b7d5f102b286e81c1ae4a8/presto-docs/src/main/sphinx/release/release-0.75.rst

Comment: This helped. Thanks.

Comment: Note: Sometimes the syntax is `json_extract(json, '$["key_name"]') AS json` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789940/3299397

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   tags -- It is column with Json string data
  ,json_extract(tags , '$.Brand') AS Brand
  ,json_extract(tags , '$.Portfolio') AS Portfolio
  ,cost
FROM
    TableName

Sample data for tags - {"Name": "pxyblob",  "Owner": "",  "Env": "prod",  "Service": "",  "Product": "",  "Portfolio": "OPSXYZ",  "Brand": "Limo",  "AssetProtectionLevel": "",  "ComponentInfo": ""}
```

Comment: Note: Sometimes the syntax is `json_extract(json, '$["key_name"]') AS json` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789940/3299397

Answer (score -1):

Here is your Correct answer.
Let Say:

---

JSON : {"Travel Date":"2017-9-22", "City": "Seattle"}
Column Name:  ITINERARY
And i wana extract 'Travel Date' form the current JSON then:

Query: **SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(ITINERARY, "$.\"Travel Date\"") from Table**

Note: Just add **\"** at starting and end of the key name.

Hope this will surely work for you need. **:)**

Comment: Note: Sometimes the syntax is `json_extract(json, '$["key_name"]') AS json` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789940/3299397