# Get specific values from JSON column in Presto

Tags: sql, database, computer-science, presto

I have a table with a JSON column `points` with one of the rows as:

```
{"0": 0.2, "1": 1.2, "2": 0.5, "15": 1.2, "20": 0.7}
```

I want to get the values for keys `"1"` and `"20"` and store them as an alias like `first` and `second` in a query. What I've done till now is:

`SELECT points, k, v from rewards CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT_TO_MAP(points, ',', ':')) AS m(k,v) where name='John'`

But this query gives me all the rows of k, v. How do I select only those two values corresponding to "1" and "20"?

Answer (score 8):

JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR did the trick.

`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(points, '$["1"]') AS first_value`

`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(points, '$["20"]') AS second_value`

Comment: just to add this also works for columns having type as varchar containing JSON data.