# Parse numbers in varchar SQL, PrestoDB

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have my table like this:

```
WITH my_table (event_date, coordinates) AS (
    values 
    ('2021-10-01','{"x":"1.0","y":"0.049"}'),
    ('2021-10-01','{"x":"0.0","y":"0.865"}'),
    ('2021-10-02','{"y":"0.5","x":"0.5"}'),
    ('2021-10-02','{"y":"0.469","x":"0.175"}'),
    ('2021-10-02','{"x":"0.954","y":"0.021"}')
) 

SELECT *
FROM my_table
```

| event_date | coordinates |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | {"x":"1.0","y":"0.049"} |
| 2021-10-01 | {"x":"0.0","y":"0.865"} |
| 2021-10-02 | {"y":"0.5","x":"0.5"} |
| 2021-10-02 | {"y":"0.469","x":"0.175"} |
| 2021-10-02 | {"x":"0.954","y":"0.021"} |

I want to parse x and y fields separately
Desired table should look like this:

| event_date | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1.0 | 0.049 |
| 2021-10-01 | 0.0 | 0.865 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.469 | 0.175 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.954 | 0.021 |

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_extract_scalar`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar) with corresponding json path:

```sql
SELECT event_date,
       json_extract_scalar(coordinates,'$.x') as x,
       json_extract_scalar(coordinates,'$.y') as y
FROM my_table;
```

Output:

| event_date | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1.0 | 0.049 |
| 2021-10-01 | 0.0 | 0.865 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.175 | 0.469 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0.954 | 0.021 |

Answer (score 2):

Try to parse the json data and extract each point alone.

Refer to this :
[Issues with JSON_EXTRACT in Presto for keys containing ' ' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271898/issues-with-json-extract-in-presto-for-keys-containing-character)

In your case, query should be :

```
select event_date,json_extract_scalar(coordinates,'$.attributes["x"]') as x, json_extract_scalar(coordinates,'$.attributes["y"]') as y;
```

UPDATE

Sorry i've forgot to remove "attributes" from the query as it was taken from the other answer :)

```
select event_date,json_extract_scalar(coordinates,'$.x') as x, json_extract_scalar(coordinates,'$.y') as y;
```

Comment: Hi, Elie!
This query returns nulls in x and y columns.